# How to check if there is no content inside a file, and how to avoid reading the last character from a file?

Tags: c

I have used comma as a separator after every string

```
        fp=fopen("log.dat","ab");
        fprintf(fp,"%s%c",enteredUsername,',');
        fclose(fp);
```

Reading from file:

```
       fp=fopen("log.dat","rb");
       int c;
       while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
       printf("%c", c);
```

How can I:
1.Avoid reading the final character inside the file,
2.Check if file is empty?

Comment: By having a one-char buffer. Is it a crime to *read* the last byte or to *report* it?

Comment: 2) Add a counter to the loop. If the counter is zero after the loop, the file was empty.

Comment: Read two characters, `c1` and `c2`. If `c2 == EOF` then `c1` was the last character in the file (possibly a `'\n'` or `','` in your specific case) ... you simply **cannot avoid reading the last character** but you definitely can sidestep the issue

Comment: thanks @wildplasser. Any suggestion on how i can do question 1?

Comment: `int c1, c2=fgetc(fp); while (c1=c2 && (c2=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: You can combine my siggestion with @WeatherVane 's. (if the counter is zero: don't output the 1-byte buffer; if the value read is EOF: jump out of the loop, and the previous value will die in the buffer)

Comment: If the last character buffer is initialised with an `int` value that is impossible to read with `fgetc()` (such as `INT_MAX`) then you can tell if there were 0 or 1 characters in the file.

Comment: @pmg it is not working, instead now first character is missed and comma is still being displayed

Comment: print `c1`, not `c2`

Comment: Also: maybe ',' is **not** the last chacacter on the last line, maybe there is a (CR)LF after it.

Comment: @user3121023: The C standard does not require `fseek` to support seeking to (or relative to) the end of a file. C 2018 7.21.9.2 3: “A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.”

Comment: @user3121023: The C standard says what I quoted. An implementation may support `SEEK_END` if it desires, but the C standard does not require it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one-character buffer like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("log.dat", "rb");
    if(fp == NULL) return;
    int prev = -1000;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(prev >= 0) {
            printf("%c", prev);
        }
        prev = c;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Input `log.dat`

```
one,two,three,
```

Output

```
one,two,three
```

Comment: From @wildplasser's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524590/how-to-check-if-there-is-no-content-inside-a-file-and-how-to-avoid-reading-the/64525154#comment114093470_64524590) maybe the comma isn't the last character. It was in my test file. I have changed the test file to be more credible. If the file was empty, `prev` will still be `< 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to avoid reading the final character? You can use the EOF in order to check if a file is empty.

```
if( (c= fgetc(fp)) == EOF){
     //do stuff
}
else{
     printf("File is empty\n")
     return 0;
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: I dont want to print final comma in the output, and the program I created puts it after every string

Comment: What if you put an if before the fprint?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
unsigned counter;

for( counter=0; 1; counter++) {
        int ch;
        char lastchar;

        ch = getc(stdin);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        if (counter) putc( lastchar, stdout);
        lastchar = ch;
        }
if (!counter) fprintf(stderr,"File was empty\n" );
else fprintf(stderr,"Read %u characters.\n", counter );

return 0;
}

// Test it with:
// echo -n "a,b,c," >bagger
// ./a.out <bagger
```

Comment: move `lastchar` definition out of the loop :)

Comment: Lastchar has been assigned a value if (counter >0). And it is only used when (counter >0). Moving it out of the loop is not needed, lastchar is never needed outside the loop.

Comment: as you have it, every time through the loop a *new* `lastchar` is created and the contents of the old one (`ch`) are lost (there's no guarantee both old and new `lastchar` share the same address)

Comment: It is output (conditionally on counter)  **before** the new value is assigned to it.

Comment: maybe `static char lastchar;` then?

Comment: Not needed. It has local scope inside the loop anyway.

Comment: there's no guarantee both old and new `lastchar` share the same address

Comment: The loop is only entered once, so the scope is only entered once.

Comment: BTW: (after inspecting the geneated assembly) all variables inside the loop live in registers; there are no adresses!.

Comment: Question too deep for comments ... I started a brand new Question about this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64525770/program-validity-lifetime-and-scope-of-variable-defined-inside-loop

Comment: For the record, the machine code that happens to be generated by an arbitrary compiler is irrelevant to this kind of discussion, unless the code is supposed to break as soon as you use it on a different platform! As I have pointed out in answer to pmg's new question, the code in this answer does indeed exhibit undefined behavior, although `lastchar`'s address, if evaluated, is guaranteed to never change.