# program validity; lifetime and scope of variable defined inside loop

Tags: c, scope, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, lifetime

Consider the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    for (int curr = 0; curr < 3; curr++) {
        int prev;
        if (curr) {
            printf("%d\n", prev); //valid; prev has 0 or 1
        }
        prev = curr;
    }
}
```

Is it valid?
What's the lifetime and scope of `prev`?

1. There will be 3 distinct `prev`s with lifetime and scope inside the `for` loop.
   The distinct `prev`s may (but are not required to) share the same address.
   Program is not valid.
2. There will be 3 `prev`s with lifetime and scope inside the `for` loop.
   The `prev`s will share the same address, behaving as if defined with `static`.
   Program is valid.
3. There will be 1 `prev`, as if it was defined outside the `for` loop.
   Program is valid.

<sup>*Note: question originated during discussion on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64525168/25324)*</sup>

Comment: 4. every variable lives in registers and the issue is moot

Answer (score 2):

1

`prev` is treated as an automatic variable that has a scope inside the loop instance

This means that at each iteration all the automatic variables are released and then
re-acquired when the loop executes again.

Actually, the definition of the `for-loop` is that the for statement executes each time (incrementing the variable, in this case) and testing the condition,
so even looking at the code you can see that the bracketed scope is finished
each time the loop ends.

Any guarantee of the address at which the local variable is allocated (or a register holding the value) is void. It is totally implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1 is correct.

Three different and distinct `prev`s that do not (need to) share address or value.

On every loop a different `prev` will be "created" and "deleted".

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of this based on what the standard says? Could it also be used to explain why https://tsnippet.trust-in-soft.com/?t=f413cfb1 (compound-literal based auto allocation, no braces around the loop body) causes UB? Why should explicitly or implicitly continuing a loop be considered to terminate the loop's body block?

Comment: This note in the standard seems to imply those semantics too https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p16. Still haven't found an explicit normative rule that mandates the behavior. I guess I'll just take it on faith, then.

Answer (score 2):

[ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is perfectly clear about that:

[image]

In the original post, `prev` has a constant address within the loop, but its value is indeterminate when evaluated. Therefore, the code exhibits undefined behavior.

I think this makes all of the answers in the original post (1-4) incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

When using C89, or when using only the supplied looping constructs constructs in later versions of C, it's impossible for code to reach a location above an automatic object's declaration within the lifetime of the object.  C99, however, added the ability to use `goto` to transfer control from a point below a declaration to a point above within the lifetime of the object declared thereby.  I'm not sure to what extent any non-contrived programs rely upon the fact that using `goto` to transfer control above the declaration of a non-VLA object does not end their lifetime, but the Standard requires that implementations make allowance for such behavior, e.g.

```
void test(void)
{
  int pass=0;
  int temp;
  int *p;
  int result;

  firstPass:
    if (pass)
    {
      temp = *p;
      goto secondPass;
    }
    pass++;
    int q=1;
    p=&q;
    q++;
    goto firstPass;          
  secondPass:
    return temp + q;
}
```

the lifetime of `q` would start when code enters `test`, and extend throughout the execution of the function even if code branches to a point above the declaration.  If execution reaches a declaration with an initializer, the value of the object is assigned at that time; if it reaches a declaration withou an initializer, the value of the object becomes indeterminate at that time, but if code jumps over the declaration the object retains its value.